# Div breaking ancestor div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I feel very idiotic for struggling with what is no doubt a very simple CSS problem: a div that breaks outside an ancestor div.
[See pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUcEE.png)

The structure of my html is this:

```
<div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 equalHeight author-card">
    <div class="usr-fav-cuisine-wrapper">
        <div class="usr-fav-cuisine-item">Chinese</div>
        <div class="usr-fav-cuisine-item">Flemish</div>
        <div class="usr-fav-cuisine-item">French</div>
        <div class="usr-fav-cuisine-item">German</div>
        <div class="usr-fav-cuisine-item">Italian</div>
        <div class="usr-fav-cuisine-item">Japanese</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.author-card {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.usr-fav-cuisine-wrapper {
    margin-left: 10px;
    max-width: 80%;
}
.usr-fav-cuisine-item {
    display: inline
```

}

The class author-card now has overflow hidden but that is no solution of course -it merely hides, and doesn't make its children run to the next line. I have also given author-card a max width, but no result. I also thought giving the parent a max-width, and giving the items themselves an inline display would have done it, but apparently not.

I'm using a bootstrap subtheme -I see that all the col-classes I am using have a float-left, but when I untick that box in my Chrome Inspector, nothing changes. I'd appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why not use the bootstrap grid system on the cuisine items?

Comment: Try adding `.usr-fav-cuisine-wrapper { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; }`. And the code you provided doesn't match the screenshot.

Comment: Michael & Brian, thanks for the suggestions -flex & flex-wrap did the trick! Thank you so much for this -I was getting really frustrated. Btw, the code didn't match the screenshot, because I left out html that wasn't really relevant for my question.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use overflow: hidden; on `.usr-fav-cuisine-wrapper` ?
But of course I realized you need to see the text that's inside the div, aka the children div's, and I answered my own question.
Try to set `margin-right` for `.usr-fav-cuisine-wrapper` the same as the left one, and use `box-sizing:inherit;` on it.

Please let me know if it works:D.

Comment: It doesn't, unfortunately: the text is now just cut off. When in my Inspector I hover over the wrapper, I see its margins are within the parent author-card, but the tags still break through it, but they're hidden by author-card's overflow:hidden. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

So you should really use `display: inline-block;` for block elements. Also note that you don't have a semicolon after your `display: inline`.

BUT, here's another way to do it using standard bootstrap classes and a slightly modified DOM to reflect it being a list.

**THE HTML**

```
<div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 equalHeight author-card">
    <ul class="usr-fav-cuisine-wrapper list-inline">
        <li class="usr-fav-cuisine-item">Chinese</li>
        <li class="usr-fav-cuisine-item">Flemish</li>
        <li class="usr-fav-cuisine-item">French</li>
        <li class="usr-fav-cuisine-item">German</li>
        <li class="usr-fav-cuisine-item">Italian</li>
        <li class="usr-fav-cuisine-item">Japanese</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**THE CSS**

```
.author-card {
    /* overflow: hidden; No sure you'll need this line */
}
.usr-fav-cuisine-wrapper {
    margin-left: 10px;
    max-width: 80%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.usr-fav-cuisine li {
    /* More CSS here if needed /*
}
```

Find details about the `list-inline` bootstrap 3 inline stuff [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#inline).

Comment: I'm away for the weekend. Will try this as soon as I get home, as I will need to adjust the display mode I have set up in Display Suite. Haven't tried inline class for ul yet -thanks for pointing me in that direction. I hope this is going to solve it.

Comment: I got this problem solved with flex & flex-wrap (see comments underneath the initial question). However, I also tried this, because I was curious to know whether it would work or not. It didn't, unfortunately -see pic at https://www.screencast.com/t/MIXZZlF2. The thing that is annoying me is that I don't see why my solution didn't work in the first place, and neither do I understand why yours doesn't either. They seem logical to me, and they should work, even inside a bootstrap framework, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: Thank you @willywilly for your feedback